Combining Zephyr's Socket API with MbedTLS for DTLS and Custom PSK Callback
I am currently working on a project where I need to use Zephyr’s socket implementation in combination with MbedTLS for DTLS. Specifically, I want to integrate MbedTLS so that I can manipulate the handshake process, particularly to modify the PSK (Pre-Shared Key) ID during the DTLS handshake.
So far, in order to create a DTLS connection I used this:
sock_fd = zsock_socket(af, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_DTLS_1_2);
which to my understanding uses Zephyr's Socket API and MbedTLS internally for security.
However, I cannot use this now because I need to manually define a callback function.
I have tried creating a UDP socket and manually use MbedTLS for security but it does not seem to work (I’m probably doing something wrong).
Example:
    mbedtls_ssl_context ssl;
    mbedtls_ssl_config conf;

    mbedtls_ssl_init(&ssl);
    mbedtls_ssl_config_init(&conf);

    // Configure the DTLS parameters
    if (mbedtls_ssl_config_defaults(&conf, 
                                MBEDTLS_SSL_IS_SERVER, // Role: Server
                                MBEDTLS_SSL_TRANSPORT_DATAGRAM, // DTLS
                                MBEDTLS_SSL_PRESET_DEFAULT) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to configure SSL\n");
        return -1;
    }

    service->data->sock_fd = zsock_socket(af, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    
    const unsigned char psk[] = {0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};
    const unsigned char psk_id[] = "PSK_Identity";

    if (mbedtls_ssl_conf_psk(&conf, psk, sizeof(psk), psk_id, sizeof(psk_id)-1) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to configure PSK\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Link socket with mbedTLS
    mbedtls_ssl_set_bio(&ssl, &service->data->sock_fd, mbedtls_net_send, mbedtls_net_recv, NULL);

    if (mbedtls_ssl_setup(&ssl, &conf) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to set up SSL\n");
        goto end;
    }

    ret = mbedtls_ssl_handshake(&ssl);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Handshake failed: %d\n", ret);
        goto end;
    }

When I run this code I get the error: Handshake failed: -28928 which translates to this define:
#define MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_BAD_INPUT_DATA                    -0x7100
Could you kindly provide guidance or resources on how to combine the native socket API of Zephyr with MbedTLS for DTLS? More specifically, I am interested in understanding how to set up a callback function that allows me to modify the PSK ID in the handshake.
NOTE: I use Zephyr version 3.5.99
************************************ EDIT ************************************
I have now come to the realization that I have defined mbedtls_net_send and mbedtls_net_recv as such:
int mbedtls_net_send(void *ctx, const unsigned char *buf, size_t len) {
    int sockfd = *(int *)ctx;  // 'ctx' is the socket descriptor
    return zsock_send(sockfd, buf, len, 0);  // Send data using Zephyr's socket API
}

// Implement mbedtls_net_recv to receive data from UDP socket
int mbedtls_net_recv(void *ctx, unsigned char *buf, size_t len) {
    int sockfd = *(int *)ctx;  // 'ctx' is the socket descriptor
    return zsock_recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);  // Receive data using Zephyr's socket API
}

I'm guessing that I need to use sendto and recvfrom for my project to work properly since it is a DTLS connection. However, I am struggling with how to pass the extra arguments required which are basically the dest_addr and dest_addr_len. Can I include them in the context? What is the "right" way to do this?

Please include the definition of psk and psk_id.

@AchimKraus Thanks, I have added them.

If it's done exactly like that, then I have no glue, what goes wrong. In the past some where passing the "char[] psk_id" as argument into a function. If so, "sizeof" stops working.

@AchimKraus Ok thank you for your time and help! I have included some additional info that may be the cause of the problem. If you have time any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Not completely sure, I mainly use NCS on top of zephyr so I may be wrong. On the client side you may also "connect" for UDP and so "send" will work instead of "sendto" (NCS). On recvfrom the "dest" is an out parameter, you only provide the variable the function will write the destination to.
